# How to fix Ansible erroring with message "template error while templating string: no filter named 'oo_prepend_strings_in_list'

Tags: ansible

I'm having issues with Ansible driven from a Jenkins instance.

Error message:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'oo_prepend_strings_in_list'. String: {{ item.reg_conf_var }}='{{ item.reg_fact_val | oo_prepend_strings_in_list(item.reg_flag ~ ' ') | join(' ') }}'"}
>       to retry, use: --limit

Code Block:

```
- name: Set registry params
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/sysconfig/docker
    regexp: '^{{ item.reg_conf_var }}=.*$'
    line: "{{ item.reg_conf_var }}='{{ item.reg_fact_val | oo_prepend_strings_in_list(item.reg_flag ~ ' ') | join(' ') }}'"
    register: set_docker
    when: item.reg_fact_val != '' and docker_check.stat.isreg is defined and docker_check.stat.isreg
    with_items:
   - reg_conf_var: ADD_REGISTRY
     reg_fact_val: "{{ docker_additional_registries | default(None, true)}}"
     reg_flag: --add-registry
   - reg_conf_var: BLOCK_REGISTRY
     reg_fact_val: "{{ docker_blocked_registries| default(None, true) }}"
     reg_flag: --block-registry
```

Value example:

```
docker_additional_registries=["registry.example.com:5000","registry.access.redhat.com"]
docker_blocked_registries=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oo_prepend_string_in_list` is not a filter provided by ansible.

If the above task runs correctly on your local computer, you have added this filter to your installation, either directly in your ansible installation (not recommended) or at the same level as your playbook or in a particular role in a `filter_plugins` directory ([example in a role](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/filter_plugins/nexus3_oss_filters.py))

If this is the case, you need to deploy that filter to jenkins in the working directory before you run your playbook.

If this is not the case and the above task is failing everywhere, you need to edit your question and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

**Edit** I was able to find a reference to your above filter in the history of the [openshift-ansible project](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible) but I had to go back to something like 2015. This filter does not exist anymore today. Where did you copy your lines from ? If you need, here is [the reference I could find](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/0952f2a35827e5f06d40d60d53d5fbcaa4f86c51/filter_plugins/oo_filters.py)